# Is it possible to passively send a Wi-Fi frame to a device not in the same network?

Tags: ieee-802.11, mac-address, linux, access-point, mobile

i want to know if it is possible to passively send Wi-Fi frames (RTS/CTS?) to a device, knowing only the mac address. If so, is there any tool, on Kali Linux, to do a such thing?

(The device is a smartphone in my Wi-Fi zone, but not in the same network.)

Comment: "_is there any tool, on kali linux, do a such thing?_" Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: If you're asking, "Can I spoof or inject packets on a wifi network?" the answer is yes, but this is not the forum for hacking.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for replaying, now i know what i'm searching for :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible based on the fact that frames are not being forwarded through to a network that is not on the same subnet.

If you are saying that the device (mobile) is on a seperate network, then you would rely on layer 3 to communicate with it as it would need to pass through a gateway. The gateway being probably a router would not forward any frames on but would remove the frame from the layer 3 packet and place a new frame around it based on information from the router and forward it on, to the next device.

Answer (score 1):

MAC addresses are only significant on the LAN on which they originated, and the frame headers containing the MAC addresses are stripped off a packet at a layer-3 boundary (router), which is necessary to get from one network to another network.

When a host needs to communicate with another host on a different network, the destination MAC address in the frame header is the MAC address of the sending host's configured gateway, not the MAC address of the destination host, which is meaningless on the sending hosts LAN. The gateway will then strip the frame from the packet, switch it to the next interface in the path toward the destination, and build a new frame for the next interface.

Comment: I think the OP is not planning to "play by the rules."

Comment: You are probably correct. You are running out of time to nominate yourself. :)

Comment: You first, my friend.  ;-p

Comment: @RonTrunk, OK, it's your turn.

Comment: Oh darn! Just missed the deadline!  Good thing there are highly qualified candidates who stepped up. :-)